# Is a good practice to quote another answers on mine?

Tags: discussion

I made a good answer with many methods to do one thing, and it had more than 80 votes, however there are a few AskUbuntu users that answered better methods and had only a few votes. I quoted it's answers on mine and said that the autor was "foo". Is that correct?

Answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/625284/387382

Comment: I'd mark such answers as community wiki. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't copy paste them myself. But I would just add a message to and link to the answer.

Comment: @Dan: The link exists. Did you visit my answer?

Comment: I think the answers can stand on their own... Just because yours is accepted it shouldn't contain all the other answers that are right - you are preventing those answers from getting proper upvotes, if you want to list answres canonical style I would suggest a table of contents in the question

Comment: @Mateo: If did you read my answer, you'll notice that I put a link to the answer and a *please upvote it*

Comment: @Mateo: Now I remind that I checked Community Wiki box as muru suggested. Before now I don't knew what does this, but now I had a bit of curiosity and googled it. Now I can't undo the Community Wiki nor recive upvotes, which is a great thing, for me as I can include answers from other users, and fo others, because they can edit my question to improve it instead of making other. You don't noticed that detail and your coment is offensive.

Comment: @muru: Please post your recommendation as an answer ans I'll accept it. And please, Mateo comment and give your opinion.

Comment: Related http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13968/edits-that-combine-answers

Comment: @Helio "*which is a great thing, for me as I can include answers from other users, and fo others, because they can edit my question to improve it instead of making other.*"  1. It might be what *you* like, but others might not like their answers incorporated. You shouldn't make the decision, it is not your answer. 2. Note that users with enough reputation *already* can edit your answer(s).

Comment: @Helio It's not about reputation! Internet money means nothing! It's about the best method being up-voted by the community to the top. Having an all in one answer, gives me no idea which is the best solution between all of them.

Comment: @Dan: Ok, now I understand it. I edited my answer. Plase check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a good practice to quote another answers on mine?

No, I wouldn't say it is.

There are answers which work well in tandem, by being based on another, or complementing  another. However, these are rare - most answers are independent of others.

It is true that people sometimes only look at the top (upvoted or accepted) answer, and not at other answers. However, it feels ... unethical ... to "profit" from another answer. If you do wish to include a selection of other great answers (with proper attribution, of course), I'd suggest making your post a community wiki.

Comment: I've already converted my answer into "community wiki". I included another answers because mine is soo long and with many points, and all the other answers are really "hidden" at the end. So I don't mind to use the rest of answers to "profit". However I don't know if as Mateo says (in a rude way indeed) is unethical yet, even as a community wiki.

Comment: I still think there isn't a reason for doing that even as a wiki - you minght not get rep for the votes - but I still feel that there are views and votes that might be taken away from the other answers, even with attribution - they see yours first with everything in in and upvote it. Overlooking the other answers.

Comment: @Mateo yes, simply copy-pasting another answer isn't good. I expected some commentary on it, maybe a note on what makes that answer good, a compare-and-contrast...

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would *never* deliberately incorporate the content of another answer into mine.

As mentioned by Mateo, there is no reason to at all: the answer already exists on the question. An answer being accepted means OP found it most usefull for him or her, while another answer might be valued best by someone else.

Being accepted by OP is also no reason whatsoever that the answer should be the "universal" one, covering all other answers. The link you include does not prevent the fact that it is borrowed, duplicated content.